# Connect Android phone to local server

Tags: android, apache, networking, connection, local

I am trying to connect my phone (android) to my local server (apache) running on Ubuntu. What I did is that I typed `ifconfig` in a terminal, got the local IP address of my computer and typed it on my phone's navigator. Unfortunatly my phone seems to find my server but is not able to connect to it, and times out. I have tried to disable my firewall but it didn't work either.

Do you have any idea why? How can I get my phone to connect my apache server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general, for Linux, ports 1-1024 can only be opened by root. Ports 1025-65535 can be opened by anyone. Open different port than 80.

Answer (score 1):

You have the ip address of your server but are you using the correct port to connect to it from your phone?  Your apache server may not be setup to host on the default 80 port (check the httpd.conf file).

Also - Don't disable your firewall but you can open the port your server is hosting on (maybe port 80 by default ?).  You can also use Wireshark or some packet capturing software to see if the request is making it to your server and how your server is replying.

Comment: My server uses default 80 port, and it is listening. I will check Wireshark thanks anyway

Comment: Is your firewall forwarding port 80

Comment: Tcp/ip requests

Comment: No it's not forwarding port 80

Comment: How do you know it is finding your server if it is timing out?

Comment: Because the error is telling me that the server takes to much time to respond